# Duplicating data from training set

Tags: machine-learning, training

Does a model trained on a larger training set created by duplicating records perform better on the test data than the one trained on data without duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

Duplicating training data for classes with fewer samples can actually improve your accuracy and that's what we call [Oversampling](https://machinelearningmastery.com/random-oversampling-and-undersampling-for-imbalanced-classification/).

But if you have balanced data and trying to duplicate then it doesn't differ from doing one more training iteration/epoch.

Comment: If you replicate your data by k folds, it is the same as doing k extra iterations/epochs on initial data. For balanced data sets, it may improve the accuracy but for unbalanced ones, experiments can only provide the answers.

Comment: I have tried a similar experiment for Regression with unbalanced data but the results didn't improve much.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful!